# Can't connect to ssl socket.io by client

Tags: node.js, https, socket.io

I created node js https server by nodejs.

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
  };
var app = express();


var server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(443,()=>{
    console.log('listen to https');
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log(' user connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('a user disconnected');
    });
});
```

after start server, when i want to connect to server by socket.io client tools like : `https:///172.16.130.3:443` i got :

> Connection to https:///172.16.130.3:443 timed out!

[image]

Comment: I did the same but configed ssl with `nginx`. `socket.io` was running on different port

Comment: Have you tried checking if your server is really listening on https:///172.16.130.3:443 by creating an express route like https:///172.16.130.3:443/home and checking if that works?

The problem cannot directly be pinpointed to socket.io until you find out if the ip and port is working

Comment: I do not use html on my server . i just write socket server with express. this is listened port on my server: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/c8FkNJKX7d/ @HealsLegodi